# Datagrid view move Scrollbar to last selected row

Tags: c#, devexpress

I am working with C# and Devexpress.

I have a devexpress GridView with around 100 records. that records will get me by backed thread.
that thread is refresh after 30 seconds.

i am showing only 20 rows and vertical scroll bar appeared.

My problem is ....
When i select 40 row, and after 30 seconds when thread works, it jump to top row of the grid Though I selected any other rows . 
I would like to scroll it to the selected row. How could I do this. Please help me.

With regards,

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your selection is cleared after refresh. So, you can use [`GridView.TopRowIndex`](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#windowsforms/DevExpressXtraGridViewsGridGridView_TopRowIndextopic) property.
Here is example:

```
//Get top row index before refresh
var topRowIndex = gridView.TopRowIndex;

//Refresh records

//Set top row index
gridView.TopRowIndex = topRowIndex;
```